# Undefined control sequence with \pagestyle{headings}

Tags: beamer

The following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello beamer world.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives me

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \undefinedpagestyle
```

while

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

and

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

work fine. Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove line 2 with the `\pagestyle{headings}` command. It makes no sense to use that in `beamer`. (Don't use `\pagestyle` at all here - it doesn't make any sense.)

Comment: There is a difference between the pagestyles empty and plain and no pagestyle at all. I want to have a heading telling the viewer which section the current slide belongs to. I thought this could be the way to go.

Comment: Have you... er... looked at Beamer's documentation at all? Pick a `theme` and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pagestyles `empty` and `plain` are defined by default, see `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\ps@empty{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo\let\@oddhead\@empty\let\@oddfoot\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty}
\def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\@oddhead\@empty\def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage
     \hfil}\let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
```

where `\ps@headings` is not. For instance, the standard classes (`article.cls`, `report.cls` and `book.cls`) define this. Hence, you can't use it in `beamer`.

Apart from that it does not makes sense to use `\pagestyle` as headers/footers are built differently here. You should just cancel it out to fix your code.

Answer (score 4):

`beamer` is not a standard class: it is a specialist class for making presentations. As such, you cannot expect that all of the standard LaTeX commands will do something appropriate or, even, be recognised.

The class provides a wide range of customisation options, including overall themes, inner themes, outer themes, font themes, colour themes and templates. Look at the documentation and/or around this site for examples.

Here is just one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}% overall theme: inner, outer & colours
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Sub-Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}
  \section{Section}
  \begin{frame}
    Hello beamer world.
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Berlin theme]

Comment: Better answer, more to the point and containing pictures *and no upvotes*? I alsways knew, that voting system is scrap.

Comment: Perhaps, but I took 10 minutes longer to write it ;). The other answer does explain why `plain` and `empty` work. Though I admit that wasn't the question....

Comment: The two answers are somewhat complementary. The accepted one gives more reason, yours gives a constructive example. Both state the most important: don't use `pagestyle` in  `beamer` class. Thanks! *upvote*